# RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock while installing django

Tags: python, django, pip, pipenv

I am trying to install django on my system using this command
`pipenv install django`

before this step, first i installed pipenv itself using pip
`pip install pipenv`

now i made my directory and when i try to install django in it, i get this error

```
Installing django...
Resolving django...
Added django to Pipfile's [packages] ...
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!
[    ] Locking...
No Python at '"E:\python installed\python.exe'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    # when invoked as python -m pip <command>
                 ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\install.py", line 672, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\routines\lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 849, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils\resolver.py", line 718, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

i deleted python and all related files many times.
tried to make my directory in different places but none of them seem to work!

Comment: i also tried to update my python version in my pipfile using pipenv install --python path\to\new\python

Comment: Have you resolved this yet? I see you're using Python 3.12. Can you try to install a lower version of Django? Perhaps Django 4

Comment: @journpy I'm still trying to solve it after one month. But now that you mentioned, I can remember that i faced this problem after updating my python. now I'm going to downgrade my python as well as django, see if anything changes.

Comment: actually i meant a lower version of django try `pip install Django==4.2.8` this should work with python 3.12 https://pypi.org/project/Django/4.2.8/